# Firebase Authentication, displayName

Tags: android, firebase, auth, firebase-android

Есть авторизация в приложении через гугл, все, вроде как, работает. Нажать кнопку, выбрать аккаунт, пройти авторизацию. В Firebase есть инфа о том, что есть новый пользователь. Кроме одного. Если выводить данные пользователя, а ИМЕННО - имя, то будет ошибка. Если что-то другое, к примеру - емейл, то все окей. Пользоватесь не null, методы работают, кроме displayName(). Как это можно решить ?

```
if (user != null) {
        toast("user not null")
        name.setText(user.email)

    }
```

Comment: как вы выводите имя?

Comment: name.setText(user.displayName)

Comment: вы на котлине пишите?

Comment: Да, на котлине.

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему. На форумах некоторые писали, что была такая проблема, и чтобы пофиксить - надо было удалить приложение, либо перезайти в профиль. Переустановка - не поможет, а вот перезаход в профиль я понял не правильно. Я перезаходил в профиль в своем приложении, а надо было перезайти в телефоне. В общем. Зашел через новый аккаунт и все работает. Хотя, все же, это странно, что половина информации профиля есть сразу, а половины нет.